# Why does Windows 10 disable the PIN login option after multiple shutdowns?

Tags: windows-10, login, login-screen

I was tuning my bootloader and had to restar my computer multiple times to test the changes. After a few reboots, when I tried to login to my Windows 10 account, the following error appeared after I typed the PIN numbers:

> Esta opção de entrada está desabilitada devido a tentativas de entrada com falha ou a desligamentos repetidos. Use outra opção de entrada ou mantenha seu dispositivo ligado pelo menos duas horas e tente novamente.

Which is the Portuguese for something in the lines of

> This login option is disabled due to invalid login attempts or repeated shutdowns. Use another login option or keep you device on for at least two hours and try again.

Which got me wondering: **why does Windows 10 disable PIN login after multiple reboots/shutdowns**?

My first guess would be to prevent someone from trying `n - 1` combinations (where `n = amount of attempts before the PIN option is disabled`), rebooting and repeating. But if that was the case, it would be reasonable to re-enable the PIN option after a successful login using the password (which is not the case).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That is why. And no, if somebody else logs in correctly using the password, they can manually reset the counter for the PIN, but it doesn't mean that whoever has been trying to boot force the PIN has given up.  The PIN is really weak. If someone is trying to brute force it, it needs to be disabled until that problem is identified or dismissed.

Comment: Yeah, but the PIN can only be used with physical access to the machine, right? So, if the user logs in, it means that it is not a bruteforce (or if it was, it is already successful), so why not re-enable the PIN option? Also, do you have any source for what you said?

Answer (score 0):

"The Account lockout threshold policy setting determines the number of failed sign-in attempts that will cause a user account to be locked. A locked account cannot be used until you reset it or until the number of minutes specified by the Account lockout duration policy setting expires. You can set a value from 1 through 999 failed sign-in attempts, or you can specify that the account will never be locked by setting the value to 0. If Account lockout threshold is set to a number greater than zero, Account lockout duration must be greater than or equal to the value of Reset account lockout counter after.

Brute force password attacks can be automated to try thousands or even millions of password combinations for any or all user accounts. Limiting the number of failed sign-ins that can be performed nearly eliminates the effectiveness of such attacks. However, it is important to note that a denial-of-service (DoS) attack could be performed on a domain that has an account lockout threshold configured. A malicious user could programmatically attempt a series of password attacks against all users in the organization. If the number of attempts is greater than the value of Account lockout threshold, the attacker could potentially lock every account.

Failed attempts to unlock a workstation can cause account lockout even if the Interactive logon: Require Domain Controller authentication to unlock workstation security option is disabled. Windows doesn’t need to contact a domain controller for an unlock if you enter the same password that you logged on with, but if you enter a different password, Windows has to contact a domain controller in case you had changed your password from another machine."

[Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/account-lockout-threshold)

Comment: That makes sense, but doesn't mention anything about the repeated shutdowns/reboots (not even on the Docs article). Do you know (or happen to have a source) for something related to that?

Comment: I haven't found anything.