# Change the Policy in Windows 10 or Windows 11 that disable the PIN login option after multiple shutdowns?

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, login, group-policy, login-screen

I’m encountering an issue with Windows 10/11 where the PIN login option is disabled after multiple shutdowns. This situation often arises due to CPU overclocking with XTU, leading to frequent reboots from blue screens or system freezes. Although I may have entered an incorrect PIN at most once, I don’t think such a stringent policy is suitable for a home PC in my case.

I’m looking for a way to modify this behavior. My current research suggests changing the threshold for incorrect PIN entries, but I’m not sure if setting the policy of account lockout  threshold value to 0 would ignore repeated reboots.

How can I adjust the system to prevent the disabling of the PIN login after multiple shutdowns or reboots? Any insights or steps to change this setting would be greatly appreciated.

Referenced Question: [Why does Windows 10 disable the PIN login option after multiple shutdowns?](https://superuser.com/q/1486426)